# Accessing Observable<any> data using attribute name

Tags: angular7, ionic4

I am fairly new to ionic4/angular7. I am having trouble accessing an attribute in an observable.

**show.service.ts**

```
getDetails(id) {
    return this.http.get(this.url+"get_shows.php?id="+id).pipe(map(results => results));
}
```

**show-details.page.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
  let id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

  this.show = this.showService.getDetails(id);

  this.name = this.show.show_name; // e.g. Breaking Bad
}
```

Is it possible to access the data this way?

Comment: you have to subscribe to get the response.. observables are lazy. you won't get response if you don't subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

First, i'm belied you don't need this `.pipe(map(results => results));`

second `http.Get` returns an `Observable` see: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient .
You should to subscribe in order of get the attribute.

```
this.showService.getDetails(id).subscribe(value => {this.show = value;});
```